# CALL Stored Procedure for every row to generate sequence number

Tags: sql-server

I have a sequence table which holds the current sequence for each year.

`sequence_table`

```
year | sequence 
18   | 1
```

I've created a stored procedure which generates a sequence and updates the current sequence in sequence table .

How do I insert a sequence for each row I need to insert like this.

```
INSERT INTO accounts_table 
select account_id, exec sp_generateSequence 
from applications_table
```

Comment: From the way you plan to use the results of the stored procedure, you should consider changing the stored procedure into a user-defined function instead. Then you can call it as part of a query which you can't do with a stored procedure.

Comment: You can't execute an SP as part of a statement. @Vlam has a great idea there, in turning it into an user defined function. Personally, I would use an inline table-value function, as these tend to perform better than a Scalar and mult-line table-value function.

Comment: But I wouldn't be able to update the sequence table if I use a function

Comment: You can always use a cursor.

Comment: @MarcGuillot that would likely perform terribly.

Comment: @Larnu That depends on the number of rows that he has to insert. It shouldn't be any problem for only a few thousand records. I don't get the general hate against cursors, they are a perfectly valid solution, easy to use, that performs reasonably well except on the most extreme situations (when you need to deal with millions of records).

Comment: @MarcGuillot I don't have a hatred against Cursors at all. What I don't like, however, is improper use of them. Using a Cursor for something that can be achieved using a dataset is almost always the "wrong" choice; as a dataset choice is more than often faster (and more efficient). There are certainly times for Cursors, yes, but I doubt this is one of them.

Comment: @Larnu AFAIK there is no dataset based solution for this problem. It has been asked many times and no one knows of a dataset-based method for calling a function/procedure for each row of the dataset.

Comment: @MarcGuillot correct, however, that why one of the suggestions is changing the task to a inline table-value function. An SP isn't designed with this type of process in mind; however, a inline table-value function is.

Comment: @Larnu, yes, but the OP has already answered that he can't use functions because it needs to change data (a sequence table), so it has to be an stored procedure, and that only leaves cursors as solution. Which aren't a bad solution for a moderate amount of records (which is usually the case).

Comment: Think it would be really useful to see what the SP is doing, in all honestly. They say they're updating a sequence table, however, maybe they could simply use a `SEQUENCE` object ([CREATE SEQUENCE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017))

Comment: @Larnu Agreed, in this case it seems that he should be using sequences.